# Where can I find online the gemara with Rashi in regular font with vowels?

Tags: talmud-gemara, rashi

Do you know if it is possible to read online the gemara with Rashi in the regular font with vowels?

I am also looking for a gemara with Rashi only with vowels, or ONLY in regular font without vowels.

Comment: Why not start practicing reading rashi writing on the chumash.

Comment: The new Koren English gemarahs also have Rashi (in Rashi script) with nekudot and punctuation. It's not online, but it is a book option if you want.

Answer (score 6):

[www.sefaria.org](http://www.sefaria.org) click through to the relevant daf and you'll find Rashi on the right side.

Answer (score 3):

Hebrewbooks.org has the [Gemara text](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=2&format=text) without vowels, and Rashi is placed at the bottom of the page in regular font without vowels. Tosafoth is also there, beneath Rashi, in regular font without vowels.

Comment: Good to see you again, Seth! It's been a while

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want can be found here https://www.themercava.com/app/books/metanav/5683
Click the arrow at the bottom of the page and double click the rashi script icon to toggle.

Answer (score 0):

You can get on dvar malchus lubavitch. The entire cycle is 7 daf pdfs a week. You can download them. They have block Hebrew rashi.
http://dvarmalchus.org/Download.aspx?History=True

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya yosef!

Comment: That would work better if there was an index of which daf is in which issue. Otherwise how would someone know where to find a specific page?